# SharePoint 2010 Sequential Workflow associated with Content Type Retention policy

Tags: sharepoint-2010, content-type, sharepoint-workflow

Hi:  I've built a simple sequential workflow that is triggered by the retention policy used by a content type.  The workflow takes the metadata of the current item and copies it to a purge log list located on a different site collection.

Having a hard time debugging this because of the retention policy relies on two timer jobs:  information management and expiration policy.  Attach the degugger to the w3wp and owetimer process but does not reliably catch the activated workflow.

My workflow history list for each file shows the workflow completed successfully.  The meat of the workflow is a codeactivity that collects the data from the current item and updates a central list.  That list is showing zero items after the process completes.  Is it the code located in the codeactivity?

I removed all of the exception handling to simplify what's being shown.

## Code

```
public Workflow1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

string purgeLogListPath = @"http://shptserver/sites/sp";
string listPath = @"http://shptserver/sites/sp/Lists/PurgeLog/AllItems.aspx";

private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{
}

private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
  {
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(purgeLogListPath))
    {
       try
       {
         SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/");
         SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl(listPath);
         DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

         SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();

         item["Title"] = onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.Item.DisplayName;
         item["Encoded Absolute URL"] = onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.ItemUrl;
         item["Content Type"] = onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.Item.ContentType.Name;
         item["Date Purged"] = today.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy");
         item["DateTime Purged"] = today.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");

         item.Update();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         string errorEntry = ex.Message;
         }
         }
         });
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really see what you question is, but for the debugging troubles try doing it like this:
1) After you deploy you should restart the Timer Service
2) Via the Central Admin you can go to Timer Jobs and choose 'Run now' to trigger the job and start debugging